# WPF Printing on Windows 10 x64 and PCL drivers

Tags: wpf, printing, .net-4.0, windows-10

I'm having issues with printing on Windows 10 x64 and some of the PCL drivers. When I print to A4 Size, it chopped off from the bottom about 2 cm and instead of printing height of 29.7cm it only prints 27.4 cm approximately.
Please note that the same code works fine on Windows 7 x64 OS.
I'm printing using the printDialog.PrintDocument() method by passing a custom paginator class.
The interesting thing I have noticed is that if I just parse the static Xaml string as below using it works fine however if I try to add the FrameworkElements in the wrapPanel using code-behind, it start failing to print on full size.

> ```
> > const string pageTemplate = @"<Border  
>              xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation'
>              xmlns:x='http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml'
>              xmlns:mc='http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006'
>
>              xmlns:d='http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008' 
>              mc:Ignorable='d'
>
>              BorderThickness='0' Name='page' Margin='0' Width='200' Height='200'>
>                 <Grid Name='grid'>  
>                     <WrapPanel Name='wrapper' Orientation='Horizontal' />                    
>                 </Grid>
>             </Border>";
>
> > var page = System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.Parse(pageTemplate) as
> > Border;
> ```

Comment: It is the difference between A4 and the US standard 8x11".  So you probably just got the wrong paper size selected.

Comment: Thanks for the comments Hans. I checked through debugging the PrintTicket's PageMediaSize selected is ISOA4. I also tried to put the hardcoded values as well in there but still the output is wrong. I don't know how those printer drivers are shifting back to US Letter size instead of A4.
I checked their properties of those drivers as well and their default setting is also A4.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the others benefit, I want to update and answer my question that I manage to solve the problem. I'm not sure if that's a bug in WPF or printer drivers but what I found is as below.
If I pass the DocumentPaginator object to the PrintDialog.PrintDocument or XpsDocumentWriter.Write methods it fails to maintain the correct page size however if I manually get the visuals for each page (although using the same paginator class) and then pass each individual page to the XpsDocumentWriter.Write method (Batch mode) then it works fine on all print drivers.
I would like someone from Microsoft expert opinion on this whether if its a bug or not and why the both methods behaves differently.